# wxPython + wxformbuilder - matplotlib in a boxSizer not respecting its boundaries (!)

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, wxformbuilder

So I have a wxform that looks like this, e.g in a sizer there are some panels. I want these to contain a matplotlib plot and a toolbar. however, in the code, they don't respect their sizes. I tried fiddling around for several hours but they just don't work (toolbar buttons don't work)

[image]

The code relevant for the matplotlib is the following.

I dont use the specific panels here because I don't know how to reference them in code or even manage the size of the windows and toolbars..

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
    FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas, \
    NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar2Wx

#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

import mainFrame


class MainFrameSub (mainFrame.MainFrame):
def __init__(self, parent, ip, product):
    mainFrame.MainFrame.__init__(self, parent)
    #self.createPlot()
    self.setStatusBar('Ready')
    self.ip = ip
    self.sizer = self.bSizer3

    self.figure = Figure()#figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)

    self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.ax.set_ylabel('Y-Label')
    self.ax.grid()
    self.ax.relim()
    self.ax.autoscale_view()
    self.ax.set_title("X-Label")

    self.canvas = FigCanvas(self, 0, self.figure)
    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
    self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Wx(self.canvas)
    self.toolbar.Realize()
    self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.toolbar.update()

    self.ax.plot()
    self.ax2 = self.ax.twinx()
    self.lines= [None] * 1
    self.lines[0], = self.ax.plot([],[])
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Basically, the question is: How do I fit a matplotlib + toolbar in one of the "sub-structures" in a window? If i have a grid with 4 views and i want the matplotlib to fit in one of them, how do I do  that in wx?